# Using discord js with an electron gui, image sending does not work

Tags: node.js, image, electron, discord.js

I have an electron app that links to a discord bot that shows different stats for the users in a server, the stats come in a png image so I tried sending them in a embed message. If I use the bot alone it works perfectly, but as soon as I try to use it throught electron, an error apears when sending the message:

```
TypeError [REQ_RESOURCE_TYPE]: The resource must be a string, Buffer or a valid file stream.
    at Function.resolveFile (...\node_modules\discord.js\src\util\DataResolver.js:135)
    at Function.resolveFile (...\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\APIMessage.js:309)
    at ...\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\APIMessage.js:241
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at APIMessage.resolveFiles ...\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\APIMessage.js:241)
    at TextChannel.send (...\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\TextBasedChannel.js:172)
    at ...\bot2.js:274
```

I've seen a question like this here [Not able to send an image attached to a message on discordjs via an electron application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62747864/not-able-to-send-an-image-attached-to-a-message-on-discordjs-via-an-electron-app)
But the solution there is dividing the bot and the electron app in 2 progrms and launching the second using cmd. I wanted to log the commands of the bot in the electron app so this solution is not that good for me. Thats why I wanted to ask if there is another way arround.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What version of discord.js are you using?

Comment: it's 12.5.3. I just upgraded from v11 becouse sending images in embed messages wasn't working